# Display message based on column value returned from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms-18

I want to create a stored procedure that returns different messages based on the data in the table. Here's what my current stored procedure looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GETLIST_ACC]
    @per_id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @status varchar(10)
    
    SELECT @status = req_status 
    FROM TOL_FILE_REQUEST 
    WHERE per_id = @per_id

    IF @status = 'A'
    BEGIN
        SET @status = 'Approved'
    END
    ELSE IF @status = 'P'
    BEGIN
        SET @status = 'Pending'
    END

    SELECT 
        req_id,
        file_no,
        req_status,
    FROM 
        TOL_FILE_REQUEST
    WHERE 
        per_id = @per_id
END
```

The table is this

```
req_id | file_no  | req_status
-------+----------+-----------
  6    | AS000001 |    A
 10    | AS000002 |    P
 11    | AS000003 |    A
 12    | AS000004 |    A
 13    | AS000005 |    A
```

But after executing the stored procedure, the following is what I got:

```
req_id | file_no  | req_status
-------+----------+-----------
  6    | AS000001 | Approved    
 10    | AS000002 | Approved    
 11    | AS000003 | Approved
 12    | AS000004 | Approved
 13    | AS000005 | Approved
```

but what I need is this:

```
req_id | file_no  | req_status
-------+----------+-----------
  6    | AS000001 | Approved    
 10    | AS000002 | Pending
 11    | AS000003 | Approved
 12    | AS000004 | Approved
 13    | AS000005 | Approved
```

From my understanding, the `req_status` follows the latest inserted data. but why? And what can I do to overcome this? I tried iterating using cursor and using a counter but the it exec multiple time instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your per_id ? This is never shown in your sample tables.   You are passing in a single value but you say you get multiple rows back - again is this a missing per_id column that isn't shown?   Please fix up the information provided.

Comment: oh, i'm so sorry, i took the table after the SP was exec. column per_id should be between req_id and file_no. the value for all these rows are 4. when executing the SP, i keyed in per_id = 4.

Comment: yes, when i entered a single value, i want all the rows with per_id = 4 to be displayed with the appropriate message. but the message being displayed only follows the latest insert.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Actually what the ```sp_``` prefix does is make SQL look for the procedure in the master  database before the user database hence slowing down the name resolution. Yes, if Microsoft release a proc with the same name in master you can also get name clashes and execute the wrong proc. Performance wise it is similar to not prefixing the proc with the schema  - again this looks in your default schema before dbo - so depending upon those settings you may also get the same performance hit.

Comment: i see. thanks for the tip guys! but i can't do anything much since i'm actually in my internship but i'll remember this for future uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it all in one statement with a `CASE` statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GETLIST_ACC]
    @per_id int

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT req_id,
           file_no,
           CASE req_status
               WHEN 'A' THEN 'Approved'
               WHEN 'P' THEN 'Pending'
               ELSE 'Unknown'
           END as req_status
    FROM TOL_FILE_REQUEST
    WHERE per_id = @per_id
END
```

Comment: It works wonders!! thank you so much sir! i didn't know the existence of CASE hahahah. once again, thank you so much!

Comment: @MariniMK . . . `CASE` **expression**, **expression**.